# R get elements from a list using another list of indices

Tags: r

I have a list of keywords.  To access a keyword on this list I type `keyword$Keyword[1]`.  I have another list, called `abc`, of indices.  If I look at the list I see:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1303496

[[2]]
[1] 2345
```

which are indices from the elements in the keyword list.

How do I use the elements from the `abc` list to list out the keywords?

I'm thinking I would use which, but which is for a vector and these are lists.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to retrieve for example: keyword$Keyword[2345]?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood well, you got something like this:

```
keyword <- list('a','b','c','d')
index <- list(1,3)
```

Now let's think you need the `keyword`s with index 1 and 3 in `index`:

```
keyword[unlist(index)]

[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "c"
```